# How can I set a background image with a custom size?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I set the background of my activity with a drawable image and give it a custom size?

The width of the background image should match the parent's but the height of background image should be x dp(s) smaller than the parent's, where I can adjust the value of x, so if my screen size is `1920 x 1080` and `x = 200`, the background image should be `1920 x 880` in size.

Can this be done using drawable or canvas?

Comment: You have to make the ImageView Programmatically, After getting the Height of the user screen set the height of the imageview `x*userScreenHeight`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically get the actual image size and set the custom size, have look this

```
  Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    ImageView iv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    int width = display.getWidth(); // return image width
    int height = display.getHeight();// return actual height
    //now set custom size
    int actual_size = height - 200;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,actual_size );
    iv.setLayoutParams(parms);

//for constraint layout

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(width,actual_size);
iv.setLayoutParams(newParams );
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Do I need to set this to any override methods or can I just define it within a method and call it at onCreate?

Comment: no need for override any method, just do it in `oncreate()` method.

Comment: Hi, another question: Currently, I am using Constrained Layout view instead of Linear Layout view. How should I edit the code you provided to suit Constrained Layout instead?

Comment: @Glenn yes ofcourse, because they all have child view of viewGroup, i update the code constraint layout.